# Custom laravel collection lost pagination meta data

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a custom collection for my model to apply a function for each item in my collection.

My controller paginate the data, but it seems like the custom collection lost all pagination meta data :

```
class Product extends Model
{

    /**
     * Create a new Eloquent Collection instance.
     *
     * @param array $models
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
     */
    public function newCollection(array $models = [])
    {
        return new ProductCollection($models);
    }
}

class ProductCollection extends Collection
{
    public function applyPrice()
    {
        $productIds = $this->pluck('id')->toArray();

        $stockPrice = ...

        return $this->transform(function (Product $product) use ($productsStockPrice) {
            if (array_key_exists($product->id, $$stockPrice)) {
                $product->price = $productsStockPrice[$product->id]['price'] ?? null;
            }

            return $product;
        });
    }
}

public function index()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        $products = Product::orderBy("name")
            ->paginate()
            ->applyPrice($healthcenter);

        return HealthcenterProductResource::collection($products);
    }
```

RESULT :

```
{
  "data": [...]
}
```

Is it possible to avoid this problem ?

Comment: LengthAwarePaginator and Collection are two different classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was to apply the `applyPrice()` function chained with the `paginate()` function.

I just replaced :

```
$products = Product::orderBy("name")
            ->paginate()
            ->applyPrice($value);
```

By :

```
$products = Product::orderBy("name")
                ->paginate()
$products->applyPrice($value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:

`toQuery()` allow generate paginate through pipe `paginate`

```
$products = Product::orderBy("name")
            ->applyPrice($healthcenter)->get()->toQuery()->paginate();
```